How to encode information on top of a protocol?
I often build appliacations where a variety of information is exchanged on top of a protocol like UART, I2C, or CAN. For example: this could be a two-wheeled robot wherein the SBC and a slave microcontroller exchange control commands and telemetry about motors and the IMU.
How should I go about encoding information above the protocol layer? In I2C slave devices like sensors, specific registers often correspond to specific settings or data values I can query.
What's a good way to choose register values or CAN addresses or put something in a UART frame that indicates what data a given transmission contains?
So far, I usually design my own scheme and include details in project documentation. But is there anything standardised so I can stop reinventing wheels?
When using a framework like ROS, this problem is somewhat resolved. I'm considering the more bare-metal-sort-of case, where such a farmework is not necessarily used.

Example of a scheme I built for a recent project where I'm pretending that the slave microcontroller has I2C-style registers



Description
"Register"
Data type
Length




Encoder positions
0x20
4 bytes per motor (int)
16 bytes


Encoder position per motor
0x21 - 0x24
4 bytes (int)
4 bytes


Motor speeds
0x25
4 bytes per motor (int)
16 bytes


Motor speed per motor
0x26 - 0x29
4 bytes (int)
4 bytes


Motor current
0x30
4 bytes per motor (int)
16 bytes


Motor current per motor
0x31 - 0x34
4 bytes (int)
16 bytes


Motor stall status
0x40
1 byte total (bool)
1 byte


Motor disconnect status
0x41
1 byte total (bool)
1 byte


IMU data (acceleration)
0x50
4 bytes per axis (int)
12 bytes


IMU data (gyroscope)
0x51
4 bytes per axis (int)
12 bytes


IMU data (magnetometer)
0x52
4 bytes per axis (int)
12 bytes


IMU data (quaternion)
0x53
4 bytes per axis (int)
16 bytes


Battery voltage
0x60
4 bytes (int)
4 bytes




Welcome to The OSI model. You don't have to use all of it of course.

@Andyaka the OSI model really doesn't fit well here (not sure it fits at all…), and it says very little about data structures to be communicated!

Is this really a question on EE domain? You can encode the information in any way you want. And if you have more than 1 byte per register, it's not really register based if you can't access each byte on it's own like on many chips, it seems like message based already, the register address being a message type and then there a variable amount of data per message. Registers would have a fixed size.

@Justme I had my doubts too... Some alternatives I considered: networking (didn't seem to cater so well to embedded context), StackOverflow (this isn't a software-only question), robotics (I think my question extends beyond robotics). Ultimately I decided this is appropriate seeing the URL of this network. If you think it better fits somewhere else, please suggest and I'll gladly migrate it.

@eccentricOrange I broadly agree with others saying you won't find a single defined standard here. That doesn't mean there aren't good designs to learn from and use to help improve what you already do. Imagine the Intel chipset. An instruction can route a transaction that may be resolved by an adjacent CPU, any number of different memories with varying rules like read-around-write, to devices on PCI, and many other connection types, including ISA bus transactions that may include hard-timed DMA. There is even the APIC system for interrupts and CPU start up and ordering. Study that.

Some home-brewed UART protocol I once made goes as SYNC | SYNC | SIZE | ID | DATA3 | DATA2 | DATA1 | DATA0 | ID | ... | CRC16_H | CRC16_L. I think something like that is quite common.

As for CAN specifically, identifiers are all about stating the nature of the data, so it is built-in there. As is the CRC. It's better than UART in pretty much every single way - personally I'm a big fan of CAN and has abandoned 1960s UART technology completely in new designs, since some 10+ years back.

There's certainly nothing wrong with what you have done, and there's no reason not to keep doing it.
Obviuosly, if there is some device you want to emulate, you'll need to follow the protocol defined in its datasheet.
In general, a lot of these physical protocols can be thought of generically as "a bidirectional stream of bytes".
It's useful to come up with a generic encoding scheme for higher-level data that maps onto a stream of bytes; then you can use that scheme on any physical interface you might encounter on a particular project.
Some protocols like I2C and SPI provide additional support in the form of a way to mark message boundaries; others (like UART) do not — for these you need an encoding method that identifies message boundaries explicitly.
Based on the number of different protocols the manufacturers of I2C and SPI devices use, I think it's safe to say that there's no well-defined standard. The most common scheme usually looks like an array of 256 8-bit registers, sometimes with auto-increment support on the register addresses, which allows reading or writing multiple sequential registers in a single transaction.

I'd like to disagree with the UART not being able to mark message boundaries. Of course it can and there are several ways. Sending a break can usually be detected as framing error. And many early MCUs implemented 9-bit data frames to implement a multi drop processor mode, the 9th bit indicating data or address/command. And still, it can even be embedded in the data stream with an escape character or using framing with packet length.

Yeah, this is what I currently do. However, while I may follow some standard between my different projects, it does require me to define my own standard. I'm looking for a way to avoid that in the interest of not making a mess that no one ever uses (see https://xkcd.com/927). Once the physical layer of the communication is sorted, is there a good way to deal with the "data layer" without requiring the heavy machinery of TCP/IP or something?

@eccentricOrange SPI and I2C are for on-board communication so they tend to be light-weight in terms of protocol overhead. Comparing those against each other makes sense, comparing them with UART, CAN or Ethernet, not so much. Also SPI in particular is notoriously poorly specified even on the hardware layer.

There are various protocols in existence which might fit. However I am doing this kind of thing quite a lot, and I mostly end up designing something to do specifically the task at hand. (For my current project we spent a lot of time looking at what already exists, and there was nothing that met all requirements.) There are other considerations other than just the kind of tasks/commands you need, such as:

do you have real time requirements? Do messages have to be delivered reliably in some period of time? Are we talking ms or seconds?
do you want a text or binary protocol? There can be advantages to being able to connect a terminal (if we are using serial) and type a command like "GOTO X Y" (say for a stepper motor controller). Or maybe you need to conservce bandwidth, in which case binary is better.
do you need specialised commands that build on lower level ones? I built a controller for XYZ stepper motors that could either do absolute positions, but which also had various limit switches and sensors which could be used for more complex operations ("go in direction X until sensor S is actiove, then stop and report your position")
what tools will you need to help with debug? Can you do everything with a terminal? A well known maker of PC based logic analysers has open source code to build your own protocol analyser, I have done this a few times and it has been invaluable.

All of these things influence design, once you have it figured out it is then a question of deciding how and where to do the work. A register based approach might be OK, which gives a small and simple command set. Or you might favour a command based approach, where operations are defined with by an enum, each enum effectively calling a custom function on the target that does ... whatever. Horses for courses, I think the more time thinking things through tends to save time later. The coding is not the hardest part.
I typically write a short document explaining things and defining important operations, and update it as the system evolves. It is always useful later, and also helps me think through the wrinkles.

Have a look at Modbus, this is a well-established protocol that does more or less what you’re describing.  Of course you’re free to implement a cut-down or variant if that’s right for your application, e.g. you might skip the checksum if you’re only running signals across a PCB.

These days PLCs tend to use Ethernet and/or Profinet and/or CANopen. Stuff like Profibus and Modbus seems to be in rapid decline, good riddance.

Agreed Modbus isn’t as common as it once was but it was an acceptable solution at the time and the reasons remain valid now; it’s established and it works, why re-invent the wheel

There are some protocols which build upon I2C:

SMBus
PMBus

From the Analog Devices article I2C Communication Protocol: Understanding I2C Primer, PMBus, and SMBus:

How Are I2C Primer, SMBus, and PMBus Related?
Originally developed to facilitate battery management systems, SMBus uses I2C hardware but adds second-level software, which ultimately allows devices to be hot swapped without restarting the system. PMBus extends SMBus by defining a set of device commands specifically designed to manage power converters, exposing device attributes such as measured voltage, current, temperature, and more.

Current Specifications explains how the PMBus and SMBus standards can be obtained if you want to see the protocols, and how they build upon the lower layers.
